# Class in a Framework not found

Tags: frameworks, xcode8

This was my first attempt at making a framework in Xcode and it's structure is something like:

framework.h
framework.m
class1.h
class1.m

I am now trying to make a console application that uses the framework. I have added it to the Linked Frameworks and Libraries, and put in the file path to the derived data folder that contains the framework into the Framework Search Paths.

When I try to build the console application, I get the error *'Class1.h' file not found*.

Am I not building the framework correctly or not including it as I should? I also tried copying the framework to my Library/Frameworks folder though it didn't put it there automatically, and I got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to make the 'Class1.h' header file public in the project headers.   I also needed to make a lot of other header files public because they were included in Class1.h, but everything builds smoothly now.